# How to disable time slots according to current time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Here i have 24 time slots of a entire day, these slots have contains one single hour for booking any property.

now i want to disable those gone time-slots which have no more uses for booking according to spent time.

**Here is a pic of those time-slots**

[image]

**here is my css for disable those time-slots**

```
.hour_slots_disabled{
     height: 40px;
     width: 75px;
     cursor: not-allowed;
     background-color: #ccc;
     border-radius: 2px;
     -o-transition:.5s;
     -ms-transition:.5s;
     -moz-transition:.5s;
     -webkit-transition:.5s;
     transition:.5s;
  }
```

Please suggest me.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP variant**

Check current hour in PHP (function `date`) and for elements containing time in the past, print class `hour_slots_disabled`.

**JavaScript variant**

Check current hour in JS (object `Date`) and for elements containing time in the future, remove class `hour_slots_disabled` (as JS should be run only after an entire page is loaded, all elements must be disabled by default).

Comment: is their another way, for change this css class according  to current time ? their are 2 types css classes here.. one is (.hour_slots_disabled) which have shown above quetion section and second one is (.hour_slots_disabled)

Comment: What do you mean with "another way"? Not set by PHP and not change by JS?